# Iterating over a list of strings: error message

Tags: python

I have a csv file that has a single column containing urls, I want to open it, convert into a list and iterate something for every url, but it gives me errors, it says the url is not a string.

```
import requests
from lxml import html, etree
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv
import pandas as pd

restaurant_urls_li = pd.read_csv(r"list_saved.csv")
restaurant_urls_li = restaurant_urls_li.iloc[:,-1:]
restaurant_urls_li = restaurant_urls_li.values.tolist()
print(restaurant_urls_li)

[['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187849-d13392251-Reviews-Kisen_Moscova-Milan_Lombardy.html'], ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187849-d17805000-Reviews-Mabuhay_Restaurant-Milan_Lombardy.html'],['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187849-d13392251-Reviews-Kisen_Moscova-Milan_Lombardy.html'], ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187849-d17805000-Reviews-Mabuhay_Restaurant-Milan_Lombardy.html'],['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187849-d13392251-Reviews-Kisen_Moscova-Milan_Lombardy.html'], ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187849-d17805000-Reviews-Mabuhay_Restaurant-Milan_Lombardy.html']]

for restaurant_url in restaurant_urls_li[0:20]:
    print(restaurant_url)
    wd.get(restaurant_url)
```

Error message:

```
InvalidArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-29d9690b9e31> in <module>()
      1 for restaurant_url in restaurant_urls_li[start:end]:
----> 2     wd.get(restaurant_url)
      3     tree = html.fromstring(wd.page_source)
      4     restaurant = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@id,"taplc_top_info")]')[0]
      5     try:

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string
```

I can't see what's wrong

Comment: Each `restaurant_url` is a *list with one string in it*, not a string.

Comment: It's not a string it's a list containing a string

Answer (score 2):

Since each `restaurant_url` is a list containing a single string, you can access it by simply accessing the first element of that list.

```
for restaurant_url in restaurant_urls_li[0:20]:
    wd.get(restaurant_url[0])
```